# Chapter cross reference not capitalized with \autoref

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, chapters, autoref

When I use `\autoref{}`, from the `hyperref` package, to cross reference a `\chapter{}`, the cross-reference in the text is not capitalized. How can I change this?

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Intro}\label{int}
HE First \autoref{int}
\chapter{Next One}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can't this way, but look at the cleveref package and it's \Cref macro

Comment: @iled That question is specifically about cross-references in `listings` environments. How does that apply here?

Comment: @cfr because that other one is an XY problem. All the answers there also apply here. One may argue then the other question should be reworded.

Comment: @iled But it is questions which are duplicates or not - not answers.

Comment: @cfr I understand your point and agree with you. However, the community voted and I believe I can't do anything now.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The quickest way is to change the information for `\autoref` which is stored in a macro named `\chapterautorefname`, defaulting to `chapter` by redefinition into being `Chapter` then.

Please note that any defined `autoref` information is stored in `\Xautorefname`, where `X` is the name of the underlying counter, e.g `chapter`, `part` etc.

A more flexible way is to use `\usepackage{cleveref}` after loading `hyperref` and replace `\autoref{int}` by `\Cref{int}`.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\renewcommand{\chapterautorefname}{Chapter}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Intro}\label{int}
HE First \autoref{int}
\chapter{Next One}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can find a list of all the available `\*autorefname` and their default values [here](https://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/hyperref-doc.html#x1-140004).